# Alguna forma de actualizar un proyecto de PHP 5.6.30 a 7.4.3

Tags: php

Comencé a trabajar en una empresa la cual llevaba un proyecto en pausa desde algunos años, el cual su versión es PHP 5.6 me piden que lo actualice a versión 7.4, solo que hay varias cosas que cambian de una versión a otra, ¿toca reescribir el código de lo que cambia manual? o hay alguna forma más fácil de hacerlo, gracias de antemano.

Comment: No hay una respuesta única, te recomiendo leer [ask] pues al momento parece basada en opiniones y terminaría cerrada, necesitas revisar por ejemplo si existen funciones de conexión como aquellas que usan mysql_* las cuales deben modificar

Comment: Esta pregunta [ya se hizo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636163/how-to-migrate-php-code-between-versions-5-7-without-rewriting-or-reviewing-al) en el SO en inglés y se cerró como indica BetaM. No hay un único camino, hay una [guía](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.php) en el sitio oficial de PHP con consideraciones pero no es un paso a paso. La sugerencia es, entonces, montar un entorno de prueba con PHP7, montar allí tu proyecto y comenzar a revisar incompatibilidades, deprecados y cambios en funciones. Luego, revisar librerías y sus versiones actualizadas.